# How to change border color of an input text on keyup in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a similar html code like this bellow:

```
<form>
     <input type='text' id='inputVal'>
</form>
```

and this jquery code:

```
maxVal = 100;
$('#inputVal').keyup(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   var insertedVal = $this.val();
   if (insertedVal > maxVal){
      $this.css({"color":"red","boder":"1px solid red"});
   }
})
```

If I put in a number that is greater than 100 the font color changes to red, just like expected. But, the border color remains unchanged. Why? How to modify my code to make the border color change red too.

Comment: Start with quoting and spelling correctly

Comment: You missed a single-quote after `#inputVal`, and the css property you are trying to modify is "bo *r* der", not "boder".
Plus, if you only want to change the color, "border-color" will be sufficient.

Comment: ok i corrected the typos

Comment: and, i had the same typo 'boder' in my code too. that fixes my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your spelled "border" wrong:

```
$this.css({"color":"red","border":"1px solid red"});
```

And (I assume this is pasting the code into SO) you forgot the end quote around your selector.

Comment: the quote error does not appear in my code (it was not a pasted in). The middle part of the function was pasted in and yeah, i had a boder typo. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
// Shorthand for $( document ).ready()
$(function() {
   maxVal = 100;
   $('#inputVal').keyup(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      var insertedVal = $this.val();
      if (insertedVal > maxVal){
         $this.css({"color":"red","border":"1px solid red"});
      }
   })
});
```

quote and spelling should be corrected

Comment: don't play smart, I assume everyone knows that if i say jquery that there is code prior to that. Just like you could have added <html> and <body> tags to my html code. common, don't be ridiculous

Comment: whats wrong? Just tested it with jsfiddle and pasted a copy. I wanted to upset anyone. Sorry